# Java literal string: wrong charset at runtime

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

I am having a charset problem with literal string in Java.

As you can see at image below, I have a static object called TITULO with a literal string constant parameter "Título". When I run the program, this String is readed as "TÃ­-tulo". I don't know why.

[image: Eclipse Debug View]

I explore the charset settings at Eclipse Project Properties Window and Tomcat settings but all them are with UTF-8 as a option.

I'm running Tomcat 7, Eclipse Helios and Windows SO.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Seems the console is set to some other encoding, cp1252 or latin1 perhaps.

Comment: Replace "this.id = id" with "this.id = TITULO".  Now does this.id have 7 characters or 6.

Comment: @DanielFischer Not necessarily the console, but maybe Eclipse in general is using the wrong charset? What happens if you let the JVM determine the string's size? Do `int len = id.length();` and see what the value of `len` is in the debugger. It may be a JVM encoding mismatch. This info is transferred over a socket when you're debugging, so maybe Eclipse is trying to determine it using a different encoding than Tomcat? Other than that, I have no clue. :3

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer. When I add `int len=id.length()` to debug it, I realize that the running code is not the same of my current code at editor. I think that Tomcat is running a very old compiled code. I tried clean all projects and Tomcat directory but don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that is in eclipse editor is not the same of the code that tomcat is executing.

I found a .war file at /target folder. I deleted this war file and works! The tomcat was running the classes from this old war file.

I have recently converted this running eclipse project to a maven project. I may have executed 'mvn package' at this process that created this war file.

Thanks all for help me found this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You might try setting the Tomcat URIEncoding to UTF-8 in the server.xml

```
<Connector port="8090" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: I tried that. But don't works. New information: I have changed my eclipse project to a maven project. I ran `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` and reloaded the project at eclipse. I have cleaned the eclipse project and Tomcat Work Directory after that.  I delete the old /bin directory from project folder. Now, I realize that tomcat is running a old code. I need discover where are this code...

Comment: Normally, Eclipse deploys the code to Tomcat here: .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the string you are looking (this.id) at is not actually the static constant string Titulo.

Somewhere in your code, you are reading the proper unicode String Titulo, converting it to a byte array, then converting it back to a String and passing it to the constructor of Style. The string is getting corrupted during the conversion.  Can't say more unless you show the stack trace of the code where you call the constructor of Style.

Comment: yes. After I changed my code to test the @Brian suggestion, now I know that my code at editor is not the running code. I am searching for this bad code.